# Long round overbracket

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, overbrace

I need to reproduce the following overbracket with oversets on sides:

[image]

Here is what I’ve got so far (don't mind Cyrillic):

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\overset{c}{410}\text{ фунтів стерлінґів} +
\overset{v}{90}\text{ фунтів стерлінґів}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{libertinus-otf}
\begin{document}
    $\overset{\rnode{C}{c}}{410}\text{ фунтів стерлінґів} +
    \overset{\rnode{V}{v}}{90}\text{ фунтів стерлінґів}$
\ncarc[angleB=180]{C}{V}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with `pstrick` is really elegant ans simple! (+1)

Comment: Thanks. `\rnode` changed the font size of overset, so I ended with manual placing pnodes:
`$\overset{c\pnode(0.1,0.05){C}}{410}\text{ фунтів стерлінґів} + \overset{\pnode(-0.1,0.05){V}v}{90}\text{ фунтів стерлінґів}$`

Comment: use `\rnode{C}{\scriptstyle c}}`